# Play framework 2 changeLanguage() (Scala)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

How do I change the language?
My failed attempt is shown below:

```
def changeLanguage(lang:String) = Action {
implicit request =>
  logger.debug("Change user lang to : " + lang)
  val title = Messages("title")(Lang(lang))
  val referrer = request.headers.get(REFERER).getOrElse("#/")
  Redirect(referrer).withLang(Lang(lang))}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my problem is that I am not connected "Lang" in view:

```
@()(implicit lang: Lang)
```